# How To change TAX Round off value

Tags: price, tax, rounding

I want to change my product tax value, it shows round off values.

My Product rate is $49.95 and tax value is 10%. It shows $5.00 but I want it to show $4.99.

I don't know where to change the round off value. I created a tax rule and it's class is properly. I think I need to edit the core files. I want to know which file to change the round off value into normal tax value.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `app\code\core\Mage\Tax\Model\Calculation.php` and somewhere on line #466 there is a function.

```
public function calcTaxAmount($price, $taxRate, $priceIncludeTax=false, $round=true)
{
    $taxRate = $taxRate/100;

    if ($priceIncludeTax) {
        $amount = $price*(1-1/(1+$taxRate));
    } else {
        $amount = $price*$taxRate;
    }

    /*if ($round) {
        return $this->round($amount);
    }*/

    return $amount;
}
```

I have just commented out the last if condition.

But please [override](http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/) it, do not make any changes in core class.

Good Luck!:)

Comment: Thanks For your answer shireen, i did the changes but Tax still shows $5.00 dollor.

Comment: Did you first try this change in core class ?

Comment: yes shireen i change the function as you mentioned above but the Tax amount still shows $5.00 dollar

Comment: I tried but it still loads $5.00 dollar tax. is there any other way to remove round off Tax value it shows like this                                                                         Subtotal  $49.95
GST or Tax $5.00